# filter is not creating a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filtering

I have a problem with the following code, and maybe I am just not understanding how filter works. From my understanding filter is supposed to return a new array. The filteredItems is what I am doing the *ngFor on in the DOM. So I first do a shallow copy of my input items array with the slice method into my filteredItems and copyItems. After that I attempt to return a new array of filtered items from the shallow copied items array. However, whenever I try to filter the array of items it actually manipulates the original array's data instead of just returning a new array with the data I need.

```
@Input() private items: Items[];

private copyItems = new Array<Items>();

public input = new FormControl();
public filteredItems = new Array<Items>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredItems = this.items.slice();
  this.copyItems = this.items.slice();

  this.subscription = this.input.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(500)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map((value) => {
      return value;
    })
    .subscribe((searchTerm) => {
      if (searchTerm) {
        this.filteredItems = this.filterItems(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        console.log(this.items);
      } else {
        this.copyItems = this.items.slice();
        this.filteredItems = this.items.slice();
      }
    });
}

private filterItems(searchTerm: string): Array<Items> {
  return this.copyItems.filter((item) => {
    let filterExists: boolean = false;
    let itemName = <string>item.name;
    if (itemName.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm)) {
      filterExists = true;
    }

    let filteredChildren =  this.filterChildren(searchTerm, item);

    if (filteredChildren.length > 0) {
      filterExists = true;
      item.children = filteredChildren;
    }

    if (filterExists)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  });
}

private filterChildren(searchTerm: string, item: Items): Array<ChildItems> {
  return item.children.filter(child => {
    let childName = <string>child.name;
    if (childName.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm)) {
      return child;
    }
  });
}
```

Can someone please tell me what the heck I am doing wrong here. I have been banging my head against my desk reworking this problem over and over for the past two days and cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first problem is that filter expects the passed in function to return true or false, rather than an item or undefined.

Comment: Hmm it does not seem to matter whether I return the item or true/false, but I have updated the code to use true/false. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I shouldn't have used the word problem. TJ's answer should resolve your actual issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`filter` does indeed create a new array, but the objects referenced in the original are also referenced by the new array, so changes to them are visible through both.

If you're going to change the state of an item in the array and don't want that change visible through the old array, you need to create a *new* item and use that in the array. That would be `map` rather than `filter` — or rather, in your case, a combination of the two.

Here's a simpler example of what you're currently doing; note how `state` becomes `2` regardless of which array we look it it in:

```js
var original = [
  {id: 1, state: 1},
  {id: 2, state: 1},
  {id: 3, state: 1}
];
var filtered = original.filter(item => {
  if (item.id % 2 == 1) {
    ++item.state;
    return item;
  }
});
console.log("original", original);
console.log("filtered", filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Sticking to existing `Array.prototype` functions, the way you'd do a mutating filter would be to use `map` then `filter` removing `undefined` entries:

```js
var original = [
  {id: 1, state: 1},
  {id: 2, state: 1},
  {id: 3, state: 1}
];
var filtered = original
  .map(item => {
    if (item.id % 2 == 1) {
      return {id: item.id, state: item.state + 1};
    }
  })
  .filter(item => !!item);
console.log("original", original);
console.log("filtered", filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Alternately, you could give yourself a `mapFilter` function:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "mapFilter", {
  value: function(callback, thisArg) {
    var rv = [];
    this.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
      var newValue = callback.call(thisArg, value, index, arr);
      if (newValue) {
        rv.push(newValue);
      }
    })
    return rv;
  }
});
var original = [
  {id: 1, state: 1},
  {id: 2, state: 1},
  {id: 3, state: 1}
];
var filtered = original
  .mapFilter(item => {
    if (item.id % 2 == 1) {
      return {id: item.id, state: item.state + 1};
    }
  });
console.log("original", original);
console.log("filtered", filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...but all the caveats about extending built-in prototypes apply (you might make it a utility you pass the array to instead).

Comment: Is this not what I am doing when creating a shallow copy of the items array and storing it in the copyItems array? The copyItems array should literally have no reference to the original items array.

Comment: @mlangwell: No, what you're doing in `slice` is creating a copy of the **array**. The items *in* it are references to the objects that are also referenced from the original array (and the filtered one once you create it). You need to copy the *objects* and have the array reference the new objects.

Comment: Ahh I see. Okay that makes complete sense. Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Wow, the filter function definitely has a gotcha there doesn't it? It does make sense that the objects would not be cloned when using it.

Answer (score -1):

No, filter is not creating a new array. In order to be sure to create a new array I would have rather use the reduce function. You can initialize the reduce function with a new array and push new values in it when meeting the right condition.

```js
const filtered = original
  .reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.id % 2 == 1) {
      acc.push({id: item.id, state: item.state + 1});
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).